# How do requirejs paths work?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, relative-path

I don't understand how path works

[image: my package structure].

common.js

```
requirejs.config({baseUrl: '../js/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: ['//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', 'lib/jquery'],
        bootstrap: 'lib/bootstrap.min',
        html5shiv: '//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/htnl5shiv',
        respond: '//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min',
        menu: 'app/smooth-sliding-menu'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {deps: ['jquery']}
    }
});
```

index.js

```
require(['../common'], function (common) {
    require(['google-map-loader', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6ZePb8iIYGAvbfL8YPflJ-o5LLtdZjGg&sensor=false"'])
});
```

1) I don't get any error in Google Console
2) I don't know what's happening.
3) I don't understand which type of path I should use (relative or absolute)

Please, give me some explanations on my questions?

Comment: "How do requirejs paths work" is too broad. You'll have to be more specific. You apparently are having a problem. You say there is no error message. (Using [`enforceDefine`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-enforceDefine) could trigger some error messages that you are not getting now.) Fair enough, but there is certainly something happening that you are not expecting to happen or something not happening that you are expecting to happen. You should mention what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The paths are normally relative, however we found that to be too complicated to maintain at work and we set our paths to be absolute.  Since we are using `MVC/C#` on the server side, it was a simple matter of just including the `requireJS` configuration data inside `_Layout.cshtml`.

You can do the same with your configuration as well.

If you are strictly Javascript, its a little trickier to figure out your path, but once you do the principle is the same.

Server side code (trimmed for clarity):

```
window.requreJsConfig = {
    paths: {
        "data": appRoot + "/Scripts/SharedData",
        "resources": appRoot + "/Scripts/resources"
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: "bootstrap"
        }
    }
};
```